# How to load a KML file into a Esri Map using ArcGIS Runtime .Net SDK (Beta)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, kml, arcgis, esri

I am developing windows store app using ESRI map. I have installed ArcGIS Runtime SDK (Beta2).

Using that SDK how can I load KML data to the map. The new Beta SDK missing of KMLLayer class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The current beta does not include KML support but we plan to add this in a future release.

The ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET product is still in beta, therefore please submit your questions and feedback in the beta forum: https://betacommunity.esri.com.

Answer (score -1):

The .NET Runtime mentions KMLs but does not give any samples on how to load them.

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/store/guide/maps-and-layers.htm

> Other types of specialized layers provide the ability to add a wide range of data and services to a map, for example WMS services and KML.

Comment: Why did someone down vote this? It's not a final answer I was just providing a bit of information to help work towards a solution.